# net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when trying to send forgot password email in production

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, google-chrome, sveltekit

I am using sveltekit version .428 on the front end and a node mailer on the back end. The mailer does 2 things sends a contact us email and a forgot password email. When in development it does both, while in production it will only send the contact us email. When ever I try to send the clients email to the mailer the browser logs `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`, I have deployed on my own server using docker as a management system.

This is my post request

```
async forgotPassword(userEmail: string): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const url: string = emailUrl + "/forgot-new";
      const email: { email: string } = { email: userEmail }; 
      const resp = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Accept: "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(email),
      });

      if (!resp.ok) {
        const data = await resp.json();
        throw data.msg;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }
```

This is in my nodejs app

```
app.post(`/eid/${version}/forgot-new`,jsonParser, async function (req, res) {
    try{
    const email = req.body.email;
    const user_id = await userRepository.checkIfEmailExists(email)
    const token = crypto.randomBytes(36).toString('base64').replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/\=/g, '');
    const exp_date = new Date();
    //1000*60*5 => 5 min
    exp_date.setTime(exp_date.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 5);
    const dateFormatted = exp_date.getFullYear() + "-" +
      (exp_date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + exp_date.getDate() +
      " " + ("00" + exp_date.getHours()).slice(-2) +
      ":" +
      ("00" + exp_date.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" +
      ("00" + exp_date.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
    await userRepository.createValidationCode(user_id, token, dateFormatted)
    await mailer.forgotPassword(email, token)
    }
    catch(err){
        throw err
    }
})
```

I have tried changing the port number, I have tried console logging the information in the browser (I got the same error code), I've tried switching browsers(I got the same error code). I've looked all over for some kind of lead on what could cause it, all I got was its caused by a google error, and they recommended that I empty my cache, refresh my IP and a few other things I performed them all and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my problem was with the environment file not being picked up when I built my docker file, that has since been changed and it works just fine.